# What do the Others call themselves?

Tags: names, lost

*LOST* features a group known by various names, including "the Others," "the Natives," "the Hostiles," and simply "Them."

However, what they call themselves is never really made clear. They only use the term "Others" when talking to outsiders.

Has their true name ever been revealed?

Comment: Maybe… “Us”? ;-)